# Table layout colspan rowspan

Tags: html

I'm trying to do this table but I don't understand how to do the white `td`.

[image]

This is what I have tried:

```
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2"></td>
    <td rowspan="2">Capacidad</td> 
    <td colspan="3">Precios por hora</td>
    <td>1er</td>
    <td>1 semana</td>
    <td>>1 semana</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This code results in the last three `td` being right after `precios por hora` not below.

Any help on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you mean?

```
<table width='100%'>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan='2'>Capacidad</td>
        <td colspan='3'>Precios por hora</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1er</td>
        <td>1 semana</td>
        <td>1 semana</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```